# Pagination Picture and Database record

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

i am busy with a php script which is suppose to show one record and one picture with a next and previous button but where my problem comes: It got a next arrow for the records and a separate next button for a picture like this [image: ScreenShot]

Basically i want when you click the next button the picture and record should change.

Here is my coding: This is for the friends.php page

```
<?php
include ("test.php");
?>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
</head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $.post( "getpicture.php", { pic: "1"}, function( data ) {
      $("#picture").html( data );
    });

    $("#picture").on("click",".get_pic", function(e){
        var picture_id = $(this).attr('data-id');
        $("#picture").html("<div style=\"margin:50px auto;width:50px;\"><img src=\"loader.gif\" /></div>");
        $.post( "getpicture.php", { pic: picture_id}, function( data ) {
            $("#picture").html( data );
        });
        return false;
    });

});
</script>
<title>Social</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="picture" align="center"> 
<!-- pictures will appear here --> 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the code for the getpicture.php :

```
    <?php

$username = "root"; //mysql username
$password = ""; //mysql password
$hostname = "localhost"; //hostname
$databasename = 'test'; //databasename

//get pic id from ajax request
if(isset($_POST["pic"]) && is_numeric($_POST["pic"]))
{
    $current_picture = filter_var($_POST["pic"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
}else{
    $current_picture=1;
}

//Connect to Database
$mysqli = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $databasename);

if ($mysqli->connect_error){   
    die('Error : ('. $mysqli->connect_errno .') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
}

//get next picture id
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT id FROM pictures WHERE id > $current_picture ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1")->fetch_object();
if($result){
    $next_id = $result->id;
}

//get previous picture id
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT id FROM pictures WHERE id < $current_picture ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1")->fetch_object();
if($result){
    $prev_id = $result->id;
}

//get details of current from database
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT PictureTitle, PictureName FROM pictures WHERE id = $current_picture LIMIT 1")->fetch_object();

if($result){

    //construct next/previous button
    $prev_button = (isset($prev_id) && $prev_id>0)?'<a href="#" data-id="'.$prev_id.'" class="get_pic"><img src="prev.png" border="0" /></a>':'';
    $next_button = (isset($next_id) && $next_id>0)?'<a href="#" data-id="'.$next_id.'" class="get_pic"><img src="next.png" border="0" /></a>':'';

    //output html
    echo '<table width="500" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td><table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td width="10%">'.$prev_button.'</td>';
    echo '<td width="80%" align="center"><h3>'.$result->PictureTitle.'</h3></td>';
    echo '<td width="10%">'.$next_button.'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    echo '</table></td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td align="center"><img src="pictures/'.$result->PictureName.'" /></td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    echo '</table>';
}
```

And lastly here is my code for the test.php where all my information from the database is going:

```
    <?php
// database connection info
$conn = @mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die(mysql_error());
$db = mysql_select_db('friends',$conn) or die(mysql_error());

// find out how many rows are in the table 
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
$r = mysql_fetch_row($result);
$numrows = $r[0];

// number of rows to show per page
$rowsperpage = 1;
// find out total pages
$totalpages = ceil($numrows / $rowsperpage);

// get the current page or set a default
if (isset($_GET['currentpage']) && is_numeric($_GET['currentpage'])) {
   // cast var as int
   $currentpage = (int) $_GET['currentpage'];
} else {
   // default page num
   $currentpage = 1;
} // end if

// if current page is greater than total pages...
if ($currentpage > $totalpages) {
   // set current page to last page
   $currentpage = $totalpages;
} // end if
// if current page is less than first page...
if ($currentpage < 1) {
   // set current page to first page
   $currentpage = 1;
} // end if

// the offset of the list, based on current page 
$offset = ($currentpage - 1) * $rowsperpage;

// get the info from the db 
$sql = "SELECT name, surname, score FROM user LIMIT $offset, $rowsperpage";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
?>
<TABLE BORDER="3" CELLPADDING="10" CELLSPACING="10">
<TD>
<table border="0" cellpadding="4">
<tr>
    <td bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><strong>Name</strong></td>
    <td bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><strong>Surname</strong></td>
    <td bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><strong>score</strong></td>
    </tr>
<?php 
 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>".$row['name']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['surname']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['score']."</td>";
            echo "</tr>";

} 
?> 
</table>
<?php

/******  build the pagination links ******/
// range of num links to show
$range = 1;

// if not on page 1, don't show back links
if ($currentpage > 1) {
   // get previous page num
   $prevpage = $currentpage - 1;
   // show < link to go back to 1 page
   echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=$prevpage' class=previous>Previous</a> ";
   $prev_button = (isset($prev_id) && $prev_id>0)?'<a href="#" data-id="'.$prev_id.'" class="get_pic"><img src="prev.png" border="0" /></a>':'';
} // end if 

// loop to show links to range of pages around current page
for ($x = ($currentpage - $range); $x < (($currentpage + $range) + 1); $x++) {
   // if it's a valid page number...
   if (($x > 0) && ($x <= $totalpages)) {
      // if we're on current page...
      if ($x == $currentpage) {
         // 'highlight' it but don't make a link
         echo " [<b>$x</b>] ";
      // if not current page...
      } else {
         // make it a link
      } // end else
   } // end if 
} // end for

// if not on last page, show forward and last page links        
if ($currentpage != $totalpages) {
   // get next page
   $nextpage = $currentpage + 1;
    // echo forward link for next page 
   echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=$nextpage' class=next>next</a> ";
   // echo forward link for lastpage

} // end if
/****** end build pagination links ******/
?>
```

Comment: It feels like you're trying to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @Strawberry Tell that to my lecturer who gave us this hard assignment when we only started learning php last week!! lol

Comment: Ah, homework- good to know.